# Get the id of multiple inserted/updated rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I insert my _as_ci accent sensitive, case-insensitive rows. Tail is unique, id is auto_increment.

`INSERT INTO tails (tail) VALUES ('Hello'), ('cafe'), ('Café') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tail = VALUES(tail);`

I could try to get the ids out like this:

`SELECT id, tail FROM tails WHERE tail IN ('Hello', 'cafe', 'Café')`

But I've had experience with it matching rows in MySQL but I can't do the exact matching process in PHP. If only PHP could collation compare.

Is there any way to get MySQL to also return the original string from the IN so I can do an exact comparison in PHP or is there a better method I'm missing?

This code is run extremely often, so I can't afford to run each insert individually.

Comment: The syntax is wrong.  `('Hello', 'cafe', 'Café')` needs to be `('Hello'), ('cafe'), ('Café')`.

Comment: @RickJames Can't believe I messed that bit up, updated the question. I probably shouldn't post questions when tired, or at least test the demo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could try to get the ids out like this:
>
> `SELECT id, tail FROM tails WHERE tail IN ('Hello', 'cafe', 'Café')`

Do

```
SELECT tails.id, tails.tail, criteria.pos
FROM tails 
JOIN ( SELECT 1 pos, 'Hello' tail UNION ALL
       SELECT 2,     'cafe'       UNION ALL
       SELECT 3,     'Café' ) criteria ON tails.tail = criteria.tail
```

and no problems with identifying (you know what `pos` to what `tail` was assigned).

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!

I also ended up returning **criteria.tail** in my result set and didn't even have to change any of my other code.

Comment: @Smeagel It doesn't matter - they're equal due to joining condition and INNER join type. But in general the use a column from the left table is recommended (in LEFT JOIN it makes sense).